# Verbose debugging from apt-get

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-sources

I've created what I *THINK* are correct local mirrors of the Ubuntu repositories locally.  When I attempt to do an apt-get install on a package that SHOULD be there, it always returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package <packagename>
```

Is there any way to get any really verbose debugging from apt-get, so I can make certain the entries in my sources.list file are correct, for example?

Comment: Try `apt-get` with the `--print-uris` option.

Comment: how about `apt-cache policy <packagename>` ?

Comment: What's in your `sources.list`? Did you run `apt-get update`?